# Google Sheets; H = C OR if empty D OR if empty E OR "empty"

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

=if((len(C2:C);C2:C;"")*(len(D2:D);D2:D;"")*(len(E2:E);E2:E;"")*(len(F2:F);F2:F;"");"")

I was going for this one, but it didn't get me far. Whats wrong; any ideas?

Comment: I want the final result written in cell G2:G
There can only be one result from EITHER C2:C OR D2:D OR E2:E OR F2:F 
Does that make more sense?

Comment: Still trying to figure that one out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(C2:C),C2:C,if(len(D2:D),D2:D,if(len(E2:E),E2:E,if(len(F2:F),F2:F,"")))))
```

Looks, row by row, first at the ColumnC cell – if populated returns that value, otherwise passes on to the ColumnD cell and if that is populated, returns that value … and so on. If it finds four blanks in a row then for that row it returns a blank.

Comment: Absolutely and want I wanted. Tx.